# What's a good Text Expander software for windows?

Tags: windows

What's a good text expander out there for windows?  Ideally it needs to work w/ MS Word, needs to be configurable in how it gets triggered, (i.e. the string hdt when followed by a space gets transformed into Help Desk Ticket, but hdt gets ignored).  And needs to have an import option where a large list of tags & expansions can be loaded.  Plugins for UltraEdit/Notepad++ would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Phrase Express](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) is probably the best, I use it daily.

[image]